# Why do I get an array of promises when getting data from the blockchain with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I am using React and getting data from the blockchain using useEffect, but the problem is that after I mapped data and put it inside lendingData array, when logged it returns an array of promises.
Code:

```
   const data = mainnet.Vaults.map((pool) => {
      const loadLendingData = async () => {
        const dataPool = await getPoolInfo(pool);
        // setLendingData((prevPool) => [...prevPool, dataPool]);
        return dataPool
      };
      return loadLendingData();
    });
    setLendingData(data)
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

Why am I getting the promises if I have used await when pulling the data?

Comment: show the `getPoolInfo` so we can assist you better

Comment: In general, when you load stuff from an API like that, you can only use state setters *inside* the async function (because otherwise the setter runs before the async operation finishes). The line you commented out looks like it should work, what happens when you use it? Also, for multiple async operations you either need a `for` - `await` loop or `Promise.all`

Comment: Yes, the commented line  works and saves the data in the array, one item per loop. And I didn't understand the setter inside the loop worked but outside the loop returns an array of promises even though I am waiting the data. So, you mean that the     setLendingData(data) outside the loop runs and saves the promise without waiting the resolve? But in that case why does this happen? When I return dataPool inside the loop the promise should have already been resolved because dataPool is awaiting for the getPoolInfo(pool), right? If that is the case then the returned dataPool is already resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should be using `map` to create an array of *promises* that you can then `await` with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
const promises = mainnet.Vaults.map(pool => getPoolInfo(pool));

const data = await Promise.all(promises);

setLendingData(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function loadLendingData is returning a promise and the map function is not waiting for it to get resolved.

```
   const data = mainnet.Vaults.map((pool) => {
  const loadLendingData = async () => {
    const dataPool = await getPoolInfo(pool);
    // setLendingData((prevPool) => [...prevPool, dataPool]);
    return dataPool
  };
  return loadLendingData;
});
const res = Promise.all[data]
setLendingData(res)
setLoading(false);
}
```